# Including Javascripts hosted on localhost in a rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a page `app/views/shared/_tcpsocket.html.erb` and am trying to include the following two javscripts:

```
<script src = 'http://localhost:8000/static/Orbited.js' content-type='application/x-javascript'></script>
```

and

```
<script src = 'http://localhost:8000/static/protocols/xmpp/xmpp.js' content-type='application/x-javascript'></script>
```

But neither of them are recognised. I have checked and the addresses are valid. How do I link to these files? Do I need a `javascript_include_tag`? I always seem to struggle linking to external .js files.

Thanks.

Comment: try setting `content-type` to `text/javascript` and remove the spaces between src, = and url

Comment: Is it getting 404 error in the browser? Can you inspect using some tools like Firebug and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you putting spaces between the `src`, `=` and value for this attribute? Try not putting these spaces there and see what results. I believe that HTML is parsing each space-separated value as its own attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this on the head.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'static/Orbited.js','static/protocols/xmpp/xmpp.js' %>
```